# How do I find which `guard` made the current request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my `auth.php`:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

],
```

Now, if both a `user` and an `admin` are logged-in in the same browser, how do I check which guard made the request?

Please note that both `Auth::guard('admin')->check()` and `Auth::check()` return `true` no matter who's making the request.

Comment: Are you having admins table in which you are storing all normal users and admin users?

Comment: Auth::guard($this->getGuard()) ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay no, separate tables

Comment: @CUGreen I disagree. I have mentioned clearly in my question that I KNOW which guard is logged in. (It's both of them) I just want to know which of them has sent this specific request.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you want to know which guard `auth()->user()` refers to - which is accessible by `auth()->guard()`

Unfortunately, there is not an existing function to actually get the *name* of the guard.  You can use `auth()->guard()->getName()` but that returns the session identifier for the guard (i.e. `login_guardname_sha1hash`) but if you need it you can extract it:

```
$guard = auth()->guard(); // Retrieve the guard
$sessionName = $guard->getName(); // Retrieve the session name for the guard
// The following extracts the name of the guard by disposing of the first
// and last sections delimited by "_"
$parts = explode("_", $sessionName);
unset($parts[count($parts)-1]);
unset($parts[0]);
$guardName = implode("_",$parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the guards defined in the application and find which of them the current user logged in with.

```
$guards = array_keys(config('auth.guards'));

return collect($guards)->first(function($guard){
    return auth()->guard($guard)->check();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It will return your current **guard** name such as `'admin'`

```
Auth::getDefaultDriver();
```