# how to laravel Auth::guard() indentification at logout

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

here is my logout controller

```
class LogoutController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
$guard=auth()->guard();
dd($guard);

        if ($guard == "admin" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            auth()->guard()->logout();

            $request->session()->flush();

            return  redirect()->route('admin.login');
        }
        if ($guard == "web" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

            auth()->guard()->logout();

            $request->session()->flush();

            return  redirect()->route('login');
        }
```

i want to detect who is asking for logout web-guard or admin-guard so that is can redirect them to their particular login page
i don't have defined roles for this because i have only these two guards 
i have checked
$guard=auth()->guard()->id();
but it gives me login guard's table row id,
i want to detect that who is requesting for logout admin or web, 
please help

Comment: Look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040390/how-do-i-find-which-guard-made-the-current-request-in-laravel

Comment: I don't understand why you made separate class for logout ....which can be done only by one method.